# Sending state array to another component to be rendered in REACT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a search input text in a NavBar component and send the results array to be rendered in another component. I can change the state in the Navbar component but I do not know how to pass the searchResults array from the NavBar component to the results array in the SEARCH component.

NavBar component:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  NavLink
} from "reactstrap";
import "./NavBar.css";
import Search from "../Search/searchMovies";

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submitSearch = this.submitSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchInput = this.handleSearchInput.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      searchText: "",
      searchResults: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }
  handleSearchInput(e) {
    this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
  }

  submitSearch = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=api&language=en-US&query=${
        this.state.searchText
      }&page=1&include_adult=false`
    )
      .then(movies => movies.json())
      .then(({ results }) => {
        this.setState({ isLoaded: true, searchResults: results });
      });
  };

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar className="Nav" color="" dark expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand className="logo" id="logo" href="/">
            <img alt="logo" src="" />
          </NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto " navbar>
              <NavItem className="searchInput">
                <input
                  placeholder="Search for movies..."
                  ref={input => (this.search = input)}
                  onChange={this.handleSearchInput}
                />
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/results">
                  <Button color="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.submitSearch}>
                    Search
                  </Button>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Search component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Button,
  CardTitle,
  CardText,
  Row,
  Col,
  CardImg
} from "reactstrap";
import "../Cards/Cards.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "../Navigation/NavBar";

export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ results: this.props.results });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, results } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div> .... Loading</div>;
    } else if (results.length === 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          Your search - {NavBar.props.results} - did not match any movies.
          Suggestions: Make sure that all words are spelled correctly.{" "}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Your Search Results!</h3>
          <Row>
            {this.props.results.map(Movie => (
              <Col sm="3">
                <Card key={Movie.id} className="Top_Rated" body>
                  <CardImg
                    top
                    width="100%"
                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${Movie.poster_path}`}
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <CardTitle className="title">{Movie.title}</CardTitle>
                  <CardText className="Text">
                    Rating:{Movie.vote_average}
                  </CardText>
                  <Link to={"/movie/" + Movie.id}>
                    <Button color="danger">Visit</Button>
                  </Link>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to send the array from component to component without redux, in the `submitSearch` function after fetching and changing the state

Comment: I know you said you don't want to use Redux, but it would really be the way to go here.

Comment: @Kars I finished the app this is the last thing to do and It will take much more time to transfer it to Redux that's why I am asking if it can be done by any other way

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap both components within a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instance and you will be able to share the results globally.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
Here is an example of the closest ancestor component.

```
    class WrapComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          searchResults: []
        }
      }

      // Arrow function, no 'bind' needed
      setSearchResults = (searchResults) => {
        this.setState(() => ({ searchResults: searchResults  }));
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <NavBar setSearchResults={this.setSearchResults} />
            <Search searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Then you can update 'searchResults' from NavBar using 'setSearchResults' from the props.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please add some explanation and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass **searchResults** as props to Search component 

NavBar component:

```
 <Button color="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.submitSearch}>
 <Search results={this.state.searchResults} />
 </Button>
```

then in Search component you can access to sate

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ results: this.props.results});
  }
```